# I want it to loop only once

Tags: loops, lua

I have a problem with looping. I want it to loop only once, but it prints constantly. If I do return, the script will stop, i don't want that, because i would have to restart server always the script would be triggered. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```lua
    local hit = GetPedLastDamageBone(ped)
    local chance = math.random(0,10) 
    local ped = PlayerPedId()
    while true do 
        Wait(0)
        if GetEntityHealth(ped) > 0 then
            if DMGByWeapon then
                if hit == 45454 or 33646 then
                    print("Foot")
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: if you want to loop only once, it means that you don't need the loop at all! I think you can remove the loop and leave everything else as it is.

Answer (score 2):

> I want it to loop only once

The whole purpose of a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops) is to execute a block of code multiple times.

So if you only want to loop once, you don't need a loop. Just remove the loop from your code.

```
local hit = GetPedLastDamageBone(ped)
local chance = math.random(0,10) 
local ped = PlayerPedId()
Wait(0)
if GetEntityHealth(ped) > 0 then
  if DMGByWeapon then
    if hit == 45454 or 33646 then
      print("Foot")
    end
  end
end
```

> but it prints constantly.

```
while true do end
```

is an infinite loop. The condition is always true and will never change so the loop will run forever.

> If I do return, the script will stop

Your script file is compiled as a chunk. [Chunks](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.2) are treated as the body of an  anonymous function. `return` will terminate that function and hence your script unless you use it inside a function definiton in that chunk.

If you want to stop a loop prematurely use `break`

Please read the Lua manual and do a beginners tutorial.

```
if hit == 45454 or 33646 then
   print("Foot")
end
```

Is eqivalent to

```
if hit == 45454 or true then
   print("Foot")
end
```

which simplifies to

```
if true then
  print("Foot")
end
```

or simply

```
print("Foot")
```

Any value that is neither `nil` nor `false` is `true`
So `33646` is logically `true`. `or`ing anything with `true` yields `true`

An if statement with a condition that is always met is pointless.

Instead of nesting several if statements you can simply combine the conditions using logical operators.

So instead of

```
if GetEntityHealth(ped) > 0 then
  if DMGByWeapon then
    if hit == 45454 or 33646 then
      print("Foot")
    end
  end
end
```

You could write

```
if GetEntityHealth(ped) > 0 and DMGByWeapon then
  print("Foot")
end
```

But if you really want to use that if statement you need to fix the condition:

```
if hit == 45454 or hit == 33646 then
  print("Foot")
end
```